# How can I add maven dependencies to the flex build path in Flex Builder 3?

Tags: apache-flex, maven-2, flexbuilder, m2eclipse

We're using maven to build a flex project using [flex-mojo's](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Home), which is great.  The problem is I can't add the swc dependencies specified in the pom to the flex build path.  As far as I can see Flex Builder only lets you use an absolute path, so it can't see the maven dependencies even when using the [m2eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) to add maven support.

Has anyone found a way to build with both maven and Flex Builder without duplicating the dependencies?

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this old thread, but did you get this working?  I can add the maven dependencies to the flex build path, but I get errors unless the SDK is in there too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex-mojos now supports doing this using the [`flexmojos:flexbuilder`](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/flex-dev-sect-flexbuilder.html) goal.  It's not perfect for nested projects but seems to work well in all other cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a particularly elegant answer, but it may serve your purposes.

You can use the maven-dependency-plugin to output the classpath to a file. The [build-classpath](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) is the relevant goal. the configuration below will output Maven's classpath to *[project directory]/target/.mavenClasspath*

You could write a small script or ant task to read the .mavenClasspath file contents and append the entries to the Eclipse .classpath. If you make the script a bit smarter and remove previous entries, then set it up as an [external builder](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm), you have a nearly integrated solution.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>output-classpath</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>build-classpath</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}.mavenClasspath</outputFile>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex Builder can now handle relative paths (see [bug report](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-12483)); you can add them to your .actionScriptProperties as follows:

```
<libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${M2_HOME}/repository/flexlib/flexlib/2.4/flexunit-2.4.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
```